# Understanding the Pearson Correlation Coefficient 

Tags: recommendation-engine

As part of the calculations to generate a [Pearson Correlation Coefficient](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2006/11/07/netflix-memoirs-using-the-pearson-correlation-coefficient.aspx), the following computation is performed:

[image]

In the second formula: `p_a,i` is the predicted rating user a would give item `i`, `n` is the number of similar users being compared to, and `ru,i` is the rating of item `i` by user `u`.

What value will be used if user `u` has not rated this item? Did I misunderstand anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link, earlier calculations in step 1 of the algorithm are over a set of items, indexed 1 to `m`, whe `m` is the total number of items in common.

Step 3 of the algorithm specifies: "To find a rating prediction for a particular user for a particular item, first select a number of users with the highest, weighted similarity scores with respect to the current ***user that have rated on the item in question***."

These calculations are performed only on the intersection of different users set of rated items.  There will be no calculations performed when a user has not rated an item.

Comment: So it means that the task of selecting a number of users with highest, weighted similarity scores(neighbors)... must be repeated k times where k  = total number of items in DB - number of rated items by user u?

Answer (score 1):

It only makes sense to calculate results if both users have rated a movie. Linear regression can be visualised as a [method of finding a straight line through a two-dimensional graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_least_squares) where one variable is plotted on the X axis and another one - on Y axis. Each combination of ratings is represented as a point on an euclidean plane [u1_rating, u2_rating]. Since you can not plot points which only have one dimension to them, you'll have to discard those cases.