# Find others pictures i may like based on votes

Tags: php, mysql

I found something thats look like what i'm searching but it's not : [SQL selecting people you may know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980112/sql-selecting-people-you-may-know)

I have a table of pictures, and a table of votes.

```
Votes (#id_pic, date, vote, ip, id_user)
Pic (#id, date ...)
```

So i'm trying to find other pictures that i may also like based on others votes compared to my votes (optionnaly, if i can give a picture for reference to start with, it'll be great.)

We'll admit that my id_user is 1, and if possible by taking a Pic for reference.

I think all the queries will be based on the votes table.
I really don't have an idea how to start or how to do it.. if someone can give me some help, i'll appreciate.

Thanks, really.

Comment: You're asking us to replicate the [music genome project](http://www.pandora.com/about/mgp) for pictures?

Comment: I didn't know the music genome project, after looking at it, it's based on multiple criteria, mine is based on only one. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: I would suggest a recommendation based off Pearson Correlation.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268956/understanding-the-pearson-correlation-coefficient I found this book a great resource on similar projects: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529321.do

Answer (score 2):

What you would do is select all the votes that match id_user 1, then grab all the id_pic for those records.

Now that you have all the pics that you voted on select all those id_pics where id_user is NOT 1 (this will give you all the other users that voted on that pic).

Finally grab all the id_pics where the id_user is 2 (or other number).

This process would be very resource intensive, therefore you might consider doing this just for one pic.